# How can I work with translated strings in my schema in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm design a schema for MongoDB and have a question. Here's an example of document that I need to save:

```
Product {
  "_id" : ObjectID("..."),
  "name" : "MyProduct",
  "category" : {Catid:ObjectID(".."), name: "Eletronic"}

}
```

This "category" refers to another collection that has all the categories...I save the 'name' inside the product because I need the name of the category when I find a Product..

But this category's name needs to be translated..

How I design this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest storing the category (or categories) as an identifier within the product and not doing denormalization. As it would be typical that you'll have an application/middle-tier/web server doing queries against the MongoDB, it's reasonable to apply a simple caching layer for categories and their translations in memory (you wouldn't even need to cache them very long if that was important).

```
Product {
  "_id" : ObjectID("..."),
  "name" : "MyProduct",
  "category" : ObjectID("..")
}

Category {
  "_id" : ObjectID("..."),
  "en-us" : "cheese",
  "de-de" : "Käse",
  "es-mx" : "queso"
}
```

Or, category could be stored with more structure to handle regional variances:

```
Category {
  "_id" : ObjectID("..."),
  "en" : { default: "cheese" }
  "de-de" : { default: "käse", "at": "käse2" }
  "es" : { default: "queso" }
}
```

If you do a query like:

```
db.products.find({ price : { $gt: 50.00 }})
```

which returns a list of matches, you can gather all of the categories from the matching product documents, and use `$in` to quickly fetch any non-cached category values for the current locale. So, you can minimize the number of extra round-trips to the database by doing the query using this technique. If you have a large set of categories to match, you might consider doing them in batches.

```
db.categories.find( { _id : { $in : [array_of_ids] } });
```

Then, match them together.

Comment: I'm doing a Rails web application...When u say about a cache layer, u say to do it in Rails...yeah?

Comment: Yeah, Rails or whatever you'd like. Memcached, etc. could also work. Somewhere "local" to the app/web server that isn't disk backed ideally. Just in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB (and most other NoSQL databases) do not support of relations.
This doesn't mean you cannot define relationships/references in NoSQL databases. It simply means there are no native query operator available.

There are two different ways to "refer" to one document from another in MongoDB :

1. Store the referred document's ID (usually an ObjectId) as a field in the referring document. This is the best approach if your app will know in which collection it has to look for the referred document. Example : {_id: ObjectId(...),category: ObjectId(...)} <- reference).
2. Not technically a reference but in a lot of cases it makes sense to embed (parts of) documents into other documents. Note that normalization of your schema should be less of a focus with NoSQL databases. Example : {_id: ObjectId(...); category: {_id: ObjectId(...), name:"xyz"}}.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go. One, like you have indicated, is called "Denormalization" where you save the category information (the name in each language) in the Product document itself. That way, when you load a Product, you already have the name in each language. You could model a Product like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(""),
    name: "MyProduct",
    category: {
        Catid: ObjectId(""),
        names: {
           en: "MyCategory",
           es: "...",
           fr: "..."
        }
    }
}
```

The other option, if the category name changes too much or you add languages regularly, is to not save the names on the category names on the product, but to rather do a query on the Category collection for the Category when you need it.

Comment: Yes, this is my point...I can't put it into the Product because I don't know when the Category would be translated and I can add languages with no control...so I can't do like the first model..
But the second, I need to make a second query to any Product...if I show 10 products, I will need to make 10 extra queries...because I can load dynamic products, so I can't do in a single extra query

Comment: Then it looks like you'll have to go with the second approach. There's no way around it. Make sure to minimize requests to the database by, for example, first getting the products, getting all of the Category IDs, then loading them Categories from the Category Collection using `{_id : { $in: listOfCategoryIds } }`